# Calculando média da sequência de while

Tags: c, while

Estou resolvendo exercícios da faculdade, porém me travei em um:

O exercício pede que eu calcule os números pares entre dois números inteiros, e que no final, eu faça a média aritmética entre os pares.

O que fiz até agora:

```
int main()
{
    int numeroum, numerodois; 

    printf("Insira dois números pares\n");
    scanf("%d", &numeroum);
    scanf("%d", &numerodois);
    printf("Os pares entre %d e %d são: \n", numeroum, numerodois);
    while (numeroum < numerodois) {
        printf("%d\n", numeroum);
        numeroum = numeroum + 2;
    }

    printf("A média de todos os números é: %d\n", );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você quer ajuda na lógica? Ou alguma dúvida no código (comandos)?

Comment: Que tal `printf("%d", (((numeroum + 1) & ~1) + (numerodois & ~1)) / 2);`?

Comment: @Andrey Parte no código e parte na lógica, porém mais no código. Não sei exatamente qual comando usar para ter uma divisão dos resultados do While.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tentei com este comando e não deu certo... não cheguei a trabalhar com o ~ ainda, não sei bem para o que serviria... se estiver certo, perdão, mas sou bem leigo hahahaah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar  o operador %2 (módulo) que retorna o resto da divisão.

Se  (numeroum%2==0)  significa que é um numero par

dentro de  um laço  ficaria assim

```
int a=0;// pra salvar  a soma de todos os valores pares
int b=0;// pra salvar a quantidade de elementos.



  while (numeroum < numerodois) {
    if(numeroum%2==0){// na linaha de  baixo você printa o número
           a=a+numeroum;
           b++;
            printf("%d\n", numeroum);//aqui basta você guardar numeroum em um array (vetor).

    }numeroum++;
   }

 printf("%d\n", a/b); // aqui você mostra  a média
```

Comment: Teria um comando para ele calcular automaticamente os números e já soltar o resultado ao executar o código, ao invés de eu colocar para somar e dividir no final? Ou ele faria isso e eu não entendi direito? Sou meio leigo ainda hahahaha

Comment: dei uma alterada no código veja se entendeu

Comment: Perfeito cara, deu certo... vou dar uma olhada para entender a lógica e o que foi feito... só dei uma colada para testar. Muito obrigado!